# Como carregar um áudio aos poucos conforme vou reproduzindo?

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo um servidor onde hospedo arquivos `.wav` (mídias de áudio). O problema é que esses àudios são muito grandes e quando vou implementar numa tag `<audio>` ou `<video>` no meu HTML, primeiro ele baixa o conteúdo completo para depois reproduzir, e isso acaba que deixando a aplicação lenta.

Existe uma forma que poderia reproduzir esse áudio em tempo de download? Ou que não precise baixar o áudio todo para depois reproduzí-lo?

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://localhost/audios/teste.wav" type="audio/wav" />
    seu navegador não suporta HTML5
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta seria colocar o atributo "preload" com o valor "auto" na tag audio:

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://localhost/audios/teste.wav" type="audio/wav" />
    seu navegador não suporta HTML5
</audio>
```